# copy value in textbox browser - Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, copy

Digitando o Id e obter o valor

```
def pedido_valor(self):

    #carregando a planilha
    extravios = "extravios_01.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(extravios)
    print(df)
    idpedido = self.driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="__qiankun_subapp_wrapper_for_vue_service_quality_index__"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/div[1]/input')
    valornota = self.driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="__qiankun_subapp_wrapper_for_vue_service_quality_index__"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]/div[1]/input').get_attribute("innerHTML")
    #valornota = self.driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="__qiankun_subapp_wrapper_for_vue_service_quality_index__"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]/div[1]/input').text

    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        idpedido.send_keys(str(row['ID']))
        time.sleep(3)
        #valornota.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        clipboard.copy(str(valornota))
        resposta = clipboard.paste()
        print(resposta)

        time.sleep(3)
        idpedido.clear()
```

Erros - `.text`
When I put this function and the output is completely blank

Erros - `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`
When I put this function and the output is completely blank

Comment: Can you provide some more detail here? What information are you trying to get exactly? How is this textbox instantiated? How is this information inserted into the textbox? Nothing in the code you provided has anything to do with `tkinter`

Comment: If getting the "value" attribute doesn't work (get_attribute method), you can execute javascript to do this... see here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: Good morning, I'm developing the automation where the python reads an excelling file where it contains varios id. I throw these Id in the field... through one for… and as soon as it's inserted, the field is automatically filled with information I need the id inserted by for.
I need to copy this value that appears in the field... and save on dataframe or export it along with the corresponding id.